# Extract a range of rows, with overlap using sed

Tags: macos, bash, unix, sed, awk

I have a (dummy) file that looks like this:

```
header
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

And I need a command that would give me different files made of rows extracted every four lines with one overlaping row. So I would have something like this:

```
1
2
3
4

3
4
5
6

5
6
7
8

7
8
9
10
```

So here is what I got (it is not much, sorry):

tail -n + 2 | sed -n 1,4p > window1.txt

But I don't know how to apply this over all the file, with an overlap.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want a file having from 1 to 4, then a second file from 3 to 6 and so on?

Comment: @fedorqui, yes exactly that

Comment: And what about the header, does it have to be in any specific file?

Comment: I forgot, I want also each window to be saved in a file.

Comment: No, I don't need the header, but every bin should be stored in a new textile, for example windows1.txt, windows2.txt, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed and split):

```
sed -nr '1{N;N;N};:a;p;$q;s/^.*\n.*\n(.*\n.*)$/\1/;N;N;ba' file | split -dl4
```

EDIT:

To make this programmable use:

```
sed -nr ':a;$!{N;s/[^\n]+/&/4;Ta};p;$q;s/.*((\n[^\n]*){2})$/\1/;D' file | 
split -dl4 file-name-prefix
```

Where `4` is the number lines per file and `2` is the number of overlap lines.

`File-name-prefix` is your chosen file name which will have numbers appended (see man split).

Comment: Hi potong, it worked. I got different files with this names: x00, x01, x02... is there a way to save those files with different names?

Comment: Could you also give an explanation? What if I want to change the parameters, so it extracts every other number, with different overlap.