# Extracting several rows with overlap using awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have a big file that looks like this (it has actually 12368 rows):

```
 Header
 175566717.000
 175570730.000
 175590376.000
 175591966.000
 175608932.000
 175612924.000
 175614836.000
 .
 .
 .
 175680016.000
 175689679.000
 175695803.000
 175696330.000
```

What I want to do is, delete the header, then extract the first 2000 lines (line 1 to 2000), then extract the lines 1500 to 3500, then 3000 to 5000 and so on...
What I mean is: extract a window of 2000 lines with an overlap of 500 lines between contiguous windows until the end of the file.

From a previous post, I got this:

```
tail -n +2 myfile.txt | awk 'BEGIN{file=1} ++count && count==2000 {print > "window"file; file++; count=500} {print > "window"file}'
```

But that isn't what I want. I don't have the 500 lines overlap and my first window has 1999 rows instead of 2000.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is wrong with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756040/extract-a-range-of-rows-with-overlap-using-sed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 awk -v i=1 -v t=2000 -v d=500 'NR>1{a[NR-1]=$0}
END{while(i<NR-1){for(k=i;k<i+t;k++)print a[k] > i".txt"; close(i".txt");i=i+t-d}}' file
```

try above line, you could change the numbers to fit your new requirement. you can define your own filenames too.

little test with t=10 (your 2000) and d=5 (your 500)

```
kent$  cat f
header
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15

kent$  awk -v i=1 -v t=10 -v d=5 'NR>1{a[NR-1]=$0}END{while(i<NR-1){for(k=i;k<i+t;k++)print a[k] > i".txt"; close(i".txt");i=i+t-d}}' f

kent$  head *.txt                                                                                                                      
==> 1.txt <==
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

==> 6.txt <==
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15

==> 11.txt <==
11
12
13
14
15
```

Comment: Hi Kent, it worked. I was trying but I couldn't figure out how to change the names of the output files. Instead of the number of first row, I want them in numerical order: 1,2,3,4... How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry that's too complicated for me, where should I put that. Thanks again!

Comment: Kent: I was trying to add that awk to a loop but couldn't. My files are called like this: Nameofpop_chr1.txt , Nameofpop_chr2.txt, etc. And I wanted to have the new files you created stored with the same name: for example: Nameofpop_chr1_window1.txt, Nameofpop_chr1_window2.txt, etc and the same for the others Nameofpop_chr2_window1.txt Nameofpop_chr2_window2.txt ...

Comment: use variables then. it is about shell variable, loop, awk variable stuff. not related to this question.  do some google, do some reading. define a shell variable, and pass it to awk, as a part of filename. @JM88

Answer (score 0):

awk is not ideal for this.  In Python you could do something like

```
with open("data") as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines()

    # remove header
    lines = lines[1:]

    # print the lines
    i = 0
    while True:
        print "\n starting window"
        if len(lines) < i+3000:
            # we're done.  whatever is left in the file will be ignored
            break
        for line in lines[i:i+3000]:
            print line[:-1] # remove \n

        i += 3000 - 500
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the entire file into memory is usually not a great idea, and in this case is not necessary.  Given a line number, you can easily compute which files it should go into.  For example:

```
awk '{
        a = int( NR / (t-d));
        b = int( (NR-t) / (t-d)) ;  
        for( f = b; f<=a; f++ ) {
            if( f >= 0 && (f * (t-d)) < NR  &&  ( NR <= f *(t-d) + t))
                print > ("window"(f+1))
        } 
    }' t=2000 d=500
```